# What is $D$ in $A \cup B= R-D$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A=\{x:x \in R, |x|<1\}$; $B=\{x:x \in R,|x-1|\ge 1\}$
what is $D$ in $A \cup B=R-D$?

My textbook's answer is $D=\{x:1\le x < 2\}$.

Is it right answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Using interval notation, notice that:
\begin{align*}
A \cup B
&= (-1, 1) \cup ((-\infty, 0] \cup [2, \infty)) \\
&= (-\infty, 1) \cup [2, \infty) \\
&= \mathbb R - [1, 2) \\
&= \mathbb R - D
\end{align*}

Comment: yes i got it..thank u very much